# Find the flux of the curl across a surface

Tags: surface-integrals

I'm solving the below exercise.

Find the flux of the curl across $S$ in the direction $n$ of the field $F$, when $S : z = x^2 + 4y^2$ lying beneath the plane $z=1$, with the normal having a positive $k$-component, and $F = \langle y, -xz, xz^2\rangle$.

I applied two methods, but the results were not same.

When I let $S : g(x, y, z) = z - x^2 - 4y^2$, ($0 \leq z \leq 1$), then $n\,d\sigma = \nabla g / |\nabla g \cdot k| \,dx\,dy = \nabla g \,dx\,dy = \langle -2x, -8y, 1 \rangle\,dx\,dy$

If I define $x = u \cos v$, $y = (u/2) \sin v$, and $z = u^2$, ($0 \leq u \leq 1$, $0 \leq v \leq 2\pi$), then $n\,d\sigma = \langle -2u \cos v, -8u \sin v, 1\rangle u\,du\,dv$

However, when I let $ S : r(u, v) = (u \cos v, (u/2) \sin v, u^2)$, ($0 \leq u \leq 1$, $0 \leq v \leq 2\pi$), then $n\,d\sigma = (\partial r/ \partial u)\times(\partial r/\partial v)\,du\,dv= \langle -u^2 \cos v, -4u^2 \sin v, u/2\rangle\,du\,dv$

Here is the problem. The former is twice as large as the latter. What's wrong with the above?

Comment: Please write this in a normal way, reading this hurts both my eyes and my brain.

Comment: How are you applying Stokes’s Theorem? You’re not following directions. Anyhow, $\nabla g$ is certainly not the unit normal.

Comment: Welcome, 이심심!  Your posts will be much easier to read if you use MathJax; see the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If you try to edit again, then you'll see the MathJax that I put in, and you can try to follow that.

Comment: @TobyBartels Thanks for your help :) I was completely confused becuz this is the first post.

Comment: @TedShifrin : While $\nabla g$ is not the unit normal, it's still normal, and $d\sigma$ is not the same as $dA$ either, which balances out. What 이심심 is using here, is that $n\,d\sigma=\nabla g\,dA$ when the surface is given by $g(x,y,z)=z-f(x,y)=0$. (A more general fact when the surface is given by $g(x,y,z)=0$ is that $n\,d\sigma=\nabla g/g_z\,dA$, but $g_z=1$ when $g(x,y,z)=z-f(x,y)$.) And I don't see an instruction to use Stokes's Theorem, just a tag; although you're right that 이심심 might *want* to use Stokes's Theorem!

Answer (score 2):

I found the error I missed. In the former calculation, I set $x = u \cos v$, $y = (u/2) \sin v$, and $z = u^2$, ($0 \leq u \leq 1$, $0 \leq v \leq 2\pi$). By applying Jacobian metrix, I get $dx\,dy = (1/2)\,u\,du\,dv$.

Thanks for your helps:) Have a nice day!!

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct, because $ d A $ is not $ u \, d u \, d v $.  But also, you might want to try a different approach.

If $ x = u \cos v $ and $ y = u / 2 \sin v $, then $$ d A = d x \, d y = \left \lvert \matrix { \cos v & - u \sin v \\ 1 / 2 \sin v & u / 2 \cos v } \right \rvert \, d u \, d v = u / 2 \, d u \, d v \text . $$  This is your missing factor of $ 2 $.

You should also be careful with this method, since $ n \, d \sigma $ is not always $ \nabla g \, d A $ when the surface is given by $ g = 0 $; the more general formula is $ \nabla g / g _ z \, d A $; that is, you must divide by the $ z $ component of the gradient.  But $ g _ z = 1 $ in this case, so that doesn't change anything; your method is correct as long as $ g $ takes the form $ z - f ( x , y ) $.

Now, you tagged this "stokes-theorem", and maybe this is part of a unit on Stokes's Theorem.  In that case, maybe you're supposed to do this differently!  Instead of integrating $ \nabla \times F \cdot n \, d \sigma $ across the surface, where $ \nabla \times F $ is the curl of $ F $, you could instead integrate $ F \cdot d r $ along the boundary of the surface.  This is often quicker.  (Or maybe you  should do it both ways, and check that you get the same result.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :) Before posting, I already solved above exercise by applying Stoke's theorem. However, I wanted to apply various integrals and get same results. Also, I skiped g_z because g_z=1. Sorry for the confusion. Have a good day.

Comment: @TedShifrin :  Yes, I wrote it backwards!  It looks like 이심심 already did it that way, but I'll still edit my post to have the correct statement.

Comment: @이심심 :  You're welcome!  If you like the answer, you can upvote it by pressing the upwards arrow next to it, and you can also press the checkmark to accept it (then it will appear at the top of the list).  You can only accept one answer (and only on your own questions), but you can upvote as many as you think are good (including on other people's questions, which helps improve the site).